# Conditions such that similar differential equations admit similar solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering whether theorem or some reasoning without actually solving the equations could immediately prove that similar equations have the same solutions.

By "similar", I mean so close that taking a limit could bring us from one equation to the other. It might be a bit unclear, perhaps there is a specific word for that, so I'll give an example.

For example, let's consider :

$\sqrt{ln(y''(x))}+a(x)e^{y(x)}+(x^5+7)^{bx^2}=0$ (eq. 1)

with $lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} (a(x))=1$ and $b$ a real

and

$\sqrt{ln(y''(x))}+e^{y(x)}+(x^5+7)^{x^2}=0$ (eq. 2)

if $y_1$ is a solution of eq. 1 and $y_2$ is a solution of eq. 2, do we have :

$lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty, b\rightarrow 1}(y_1(x))=y_2(x)$ ?

Are there general conditions on the equations which, when fulfilled, automatically lead to this conclusion ?